# WebPack hot reload with Vue.js and .NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, vue.js, webpack

I'm trying to integrate Vue.js (which I'm also new to) with an existing .NET MVC project. This is so that I can give Vue a try in certain Areas of the application where I think it would be appropriate.

I have followed a couple of guides for doing this:

- https://medium.com/corebuild-software/vue-js-and-net-mvc-b5cede228626
- https://medium.com/@hyounoosung/integrating-vue-js-2-0-to-net-mvc5-project-f97eb5a5b3ad

It seems that everything has gone alright so far but I've noticed that the hot reloading is not working. When I run the webpack server, I can see that it's detecting the changes and recompiling the file(s) but nothing happens in the browser. Infact, nothing happens even when I manually refresh or hard-refresh the page. If I stop the application and then run it again, only then does it update.

Here's is the simple setup I have so far...

I have a new MVC Area with a single view in it with the following folder structure:

[image]

**WebpackTest/Views/index.html**:

```
<div id="app">
  <h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>
  {{ vueMessage }}
</div>

@section Scripts {
  <script src="~/bundle/webpacktest.js"></script>
}
```

I then have a scripts folder which contains my Vue code:

[image]

**scripts/webpacktest/main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      vueMessage: 'Message from Vue'
    }
  }
})
```

Here is my **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "description": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Andy Furniss",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.9.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.11"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.7.1"
  }
}
```

...and my **webpack.config.js**:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

var fs = require('fs')
var appBasePath = './Scripts/app/'
var jsEntries = {}
// We search for index.js files inside basePath folder and make those as entries
fs.readdirSync(appBasePath).forEach(function (name) {
  var indexFile = appBasePath + name + '/main.js'
  if (fs.existsSync(indexFile)) {
    jsEntries[name] = indexFile
  }
})

module.exports = {
  entry: jsEntries,
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './wwwroot/bundle/'),
    publicPath: '/wwwroot/bundle/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
            // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
            // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
            'scss': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader'
            ],
            'sass': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
            ]
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '*': {
        target: 'https://localhost:44369/',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false
      },
      port: 8080,
      host: '0.0.0.0',
      hot: true,
      inline: true
    }
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

When I change the message in **main.js**, nothing happens, even if I refresh even though the webpack server is telling me things are happening.

Comment: If you do a hard refresh, are your code changes reflected on the webpage? (After webpack's console said it finished compiling)

Comment: No, they are not. It's odd because the console is saying it's updated webpacktest.js (which is the output file) but when I check it's contents, it hasn't changed.

Comment: I'm very confused now. When I go to http://localhost:8080/wwwroot/bundle/webpacktest.js I can see my changes but in Visual Studio and on the actual webpage where the changes should be displayed, they aren't there.

Comment: @AndyFurniss did you ever figure this out? I'm looking at the same issue. The answer below appears complex and this current setup appears to be working perfectly, minus the hot reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Hot reload cannot work if you physically write files to the disk.

I created this template that combines **.NET MVC** with **Vue.js**. You can use the entire Vue ecosystem but if you don't want it on any page you can just opt out.

GitHub: https://github.com/danijelh/aspnetcore-vue-typescript-template

Medium: https://medium.com/@danijelhdev/multi-page-net-core-with-vue-js-typescript-vuex-vue-router-bulma-sass-and-webpack-4-efc7de83fea4

You can use it as an example or starting point.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to startup.cs

```
  app.Run(async (context) =>
  {
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
    await context.Response.SendFileAsync(Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "index.html"));
  });
```